# Kill usage alert keeps popping up

Tags: bash

I keep getting the following message whenever I run my bash script:

```
kill: usage kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

This is the line it happens on, when I am trying to kill all instances of methserver:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep '[m]ethserver' | awk '{print $2}')
```

How do I fix it? Would like to get rid of this annoying message!

Comment: Well, what's the output of `ps aux | grep '[m]ethserver' | awk '{print $2}'` in such a case (when the message pops up)?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you're giving it bad input or it wouldn't be outputting a usage message. In any case, [there is a tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill) to do this for you.

```
pkill methserver
```